# How to refer a bean declared in spring context xml from an annotated class spring

Tags: xml, spring, annotations

Example:

spring context xml

```
<beans>
<bean id="a" class="ClassA" />
</beans>
```

@Service
public class Test {

@Resource InterfaceA ifcA;

}

public class ClassA implements InterfaceA {
}

public interface InterfaceA {
}

---

I would like to know how I can refer to xml bean declared in xml from a java class that has annotations enabled.

One way I know would be get the context and then get the bean.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your annotated class, declare this

```
@Autowired InterfaceA ifcA;
```

Spring will automatically populate with the appropriate bean instance.

Comment: So I don't need to annotate the Implementation i.e. ClassA with @Component/@Service right, since it is already mentioned in xml.

Comment: That's correct. ClassA doesn't need any type level annotation as long as its instantiated in the context xml as you are doing.

Comment: BTW, how are you instantiating the Test class?

Comment: I am migrating dependency injection xml based to annotations. I would like to use <context:annotation-config/> in the xml and remove all the bean definitions.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work out of the box since Spring takes care of @Resource annotations as well. It looks up the corresponding bean by the requested type (that's why it's called "autowiring by type").

You may alternatively specify the name of the bean using `@Resource(name="a")` or `@Autowired @Qualifier("A")` at the `ifcA` variable. Since you specify the name of the bean here, it is called "autowiring by name".